# I need help to remove hard coded values from kafka-python consumer

Tags: python, kafka-python

like :

```
topic_name = "auto-remediation"
address = "sape-zookeeper-1"
```

I need to remove hard coded values and pass the variable here :

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer(b'auto-remediation', bootstrap_servers='sape-zookeeper-1:9092')
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is hardcoded in kafka-python consumer. You can replace any parameter with a variable. Just make sure that the variables are initialized and have correct string in them before you create client object like:

> topic_name = "auto-remediation"
>
> address = "sape-zookeeper-1"
>
> consumer = KafkaConsumer(topic_name, bootstrap_servers=address)